# How to make template classes forward-declareable

Tags: c++

I had this sweet little setup planned out (well, i thought it was sweet):

```
template< typename T>
class CInterfaceT
{
    //a purely virtual interface declaration
};


template< typename T, typename SomeOtherStuff >
class CImplementationT : public CInterfaceT<T>
{
    //implemenation stuff
};
```

then:

```
typedef CInterfaceT<CFoo> IFooInterface;
typedef CInterface<CBar>  IBarInterface;

class CObnoxiousHolder
{
public:
IFooInterface* GetFoo() { return &m_Foo; }
IBarInterface* GetBar() { return &m_Bar; }

private:
CImplementationT <CFoo, someting>  m_Foo;
CImplementationT <CBar, otherting> m_Bar;
};
```

The problem is, those typedefed "interfaces" have to be used in a C++ CLI project that relies on something like the following to import unmanaged code:

```
class IFooInterface;
typedef IFooInterface CFooCppInterface;
```

Which, apparently, works. Or used to work with properly declared interface classes and doesn't work now because you cant forward-declare a template instance.

The knee jerk solution is to declare some proper interface classes instead of typedefs:

```
class IFooInterface : public CInterfaceT<CFoo> {};
class IBarInterface : public CInterfaceT<CBar> {};
```

but this screws up the GetFoo()-alike getter methods because these new interfaces have very little to do with proper implementation classes now.

I still really like the template approach here since it saves quite a bit of boilerplate. How can I fix it?

Edit: the solution is simple: use more templates!

```
template< typename T, typename Q, typename SomeOtherStuff >
class CImplementationT : public Q
{
    //implemenation stuff
};
```

Comment: i can't make heads or tails of this question. it seems the typedef is already there in `typedef CInterfaceT<CFoo> IFooInterface;`

Comment: it is, in CLI project. Apparently that's kosher there.

Comment: if I understand correctly you only need to forward declare an explicit specialisation of a template, which is the same as forward declare a class with more syntax: `template<> class CInterfaceT<CFoo>` instead of `class IFooInterface;`. Could you please elaborate? Where are declarations/ where are they needed?

Comment: It might help if you give us more detail how it "doesn't work now"? Are there compilation errors? Linker errors? Runtime errors? Something else?

Comment: I see no forward declarations in the first 2 code blocks, maybe that's your problem. `typedef` is no forward declaration, just a type alias.

Comment: I know very little about CLI C++, the exact problem was explained to me in these exact words - templates are a no go, make them proper classes.

Comment: @Excelcius `class IFooInterface;` that is a forward declaration of a class asumming I am following OP. The same can be done with (fully specialised) templates however, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @user3125280 Yes that's why I said _in the first 2 code blocks_. I am guessing the part of the question containing `class IFooInterface` is not part of the code causing the problem but rather added info. However, I might have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @obamator what is c++ cli? also what is managed code?

Comment: @BЈовић C++/CLI is a special extension of C++ which enables you to easily call .NET assemblies from a platform-compiled C++ program (interop). In this context, "managed" refers to .NET-Code (C#, VB.net, etc...), while native refers to code which produces regular, platform-specific binaries (traditional C++). It's an extension by Microsoft offered in Visual Studio and since it uses it's own compiler, sometimes some C++ features which work in the regular compiler, fail to compile in the C++/CLI-compiler. But I don't think that's the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - do you need something like this?

```
template<> class CInterfaceT<CFoo>;
typedef CInterfaceT<CFoo> CFooCppInterface;
```

instead of;

```
class IFooInterface;
typedef IFooInterface CFooCppInterface;
```

It is the *partially specialised* templates that can't be forward declared.

Answer (score 0):

Post edit, basically - I used static polymorphism when implementing template interfaces instead of a proper one.